# How to export animated emission to Unity?

Tags: transparency, unity, emission

I have made the following animation in Blender:

[image]

It is a cube with a slightly bigger cube around it that has the wireframe modifier on it.
The moving light I made this way, I'm using emission, transparency, noise, and I'm animating the noise's Y coordinate:

[image]

I would have to use this cube and the animation in Unity, so I need a way, even if it's complicated, to make it usable in Unity, because right now the animation is fully gone. Is there a trick or something to be able to use this in Unity? I do not mind if I have to look into other software (Unity shaders for example), I just really need this kind of effect, even if it takes a lot of time to do and a lot of learning along the way.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: I see, I was expecting this actually, I guess I wasn't specific enough about my question, I'm looking for the solution no matter if I have to look into Unity shaders, I really have to get this to work no matter the way and no matter what I need to use and how long it is going to take.

Comment: Well either you bake that animated procedural texture into a static image texture and animate UVs in Unity, or you bake it into a video, both accepting the fact that it might look like it is looping. Otherwise you'll have to rebuild the setup in Unity, which is something we can not help you with here.